# How do I declare a method in C++/CLI that will be seen as an extension method in C#?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, extension-methods

I'm writing a .NET assembly in C++/CLI to be used in our C#-based application.  I'd like the application to see some of the C++ methods as extension methods.  Is there some attribute I can apply to the declaration to specify that a method should be seen as an extension method from C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it a static method in a non-nested, non-generic static class, with the [`Extension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute.aspx) attribute applied to both the class and the method.

The tricky bit here *may* be the concept of a static class - that may not exist in C++/CLI... I'm not sure. It's possible that the C# compiler doesn't really care whether or not the class is static when *detecting* an extension method, only when declaring one. It's certainly worth a try without it.

Comment: "It's possible that the C# compiler doesn't really care whether or not the class is static _when detecting an extension method_"... It doesn't, which is consistent with the C# spec.

Comment: @TomBlodget: So you've managed to create an extension method on a non-static class, in IL, and the C# compiler was fine with it? Interesting. The spec talks about "an extension method is eligible if..." in 7.6.5.2, whereas section 10.6.9 says that "Extension methods can be declared only in nongeneric, non-nested static classes" - so I don't think it *is* consistent with the C# spec in that respect.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and here is a little example of an extension method in C++/CLI:

```
using namespace System;

namespace CPPLib 
{
    [System::Runtime::CompilerServices::Extension]
    public ref class StringExtensions abstract sealed
    {
    public: 
        [System::Runtime::CompilerServices::Extension]
        static bool MyIsNullOrEmpty(String^ s)
        {
            return String::IsNullOrEmpty(s);
        }
    };
}
```

This extension method can be used just like any other in C#:

```
using CPPLib;

namespace CShartClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {

            string a = null;
            Console.WriteLine( a.MyIsNullOrEmpty() ? "Null Or Empty" : "Not empty" );
            a = "Test";
            Console.WriteLine( a.MyIsNullOrEmpty() ? "Null Or Empty" : "Not empty" );
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it seems C++ does not provide us with the "syntactic sugar" like in C#. At least I did not find it.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can. Extension methods are merely syntactic sugar, converted to static methods by the compiler.